# MediaWiki destroys CSS aesthetics for <code> tag

Tags: html, css, content, mediawiki, users

In `MediaWiki:Common.css` I gave these essential directives:

```
code {
    display: block;
}
```

then I created an article with this content:

```
<code>
<x>
    <y>
        <z></z>
    </y>
</x>
</code>
```

After saving it looks like this:

[image]

Although I used only one `<code>` tag the DOM markup includes four different `<code>` blocks while the most inner part also gets a `<pre>` tag I never created.
This all seems to come not from HTML or CSS, but from MediaWiki itself.

How could I prevent MediaWiki from altering my code this way?

Comment: This is a programming question and nothing to do with running a web site: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading whitespace creates a `<pre>` block in wikitext. Try using the [SyntaxHighlight extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight) instead.

Comment: Indent the whole code block, that will result in a single `<pre>` block (as opposed to the several `<pre>` and `<p>` blocks you have now).

Comment: You can indent with space.

Comment: Indenting the whole code block with space is something I prefer not to do. Is there a way to indent in MediaWiki with an indentation character directly from keyboard (hitting `TAB` doesn't help as it would in VSCODE)?

Comment: What the tab key does depends on your editor, not the markup language ([CodeEditor](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CodeEditor) can indent via tab key for example, it's not really meant for editing wikitext though). And a raw tab character wouldn't work anyway, preformatted text needs to be indented with spaces.